# Does finite variance imply on a finite mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Assume that a random variable has a finite variance. Does it mean it also has a finite mean?

My approach: I think since it has a finite variance, it means it is in $\mathcal{L}_2$ space of the probability measure $\mu$. Therefore, it should be in $\mathcal{L}_1$ space of the probability measure $\mu$ and thus the mean is finite.

IS that correct?

Comment: How can you define the variance, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2],$$ without knowing the expected value $\mu=\mathbb{E}[X]$?

Comment: Anyway, by Jensen's inequality $$\mathbb{E}[X]^2\leq \mathbb{E}[X^2].$$

Comment: My answer to your first part: the mean may exist but it can go to infinity, right? However, E[X^2]-E[X]^2 may be still finite. I agree with the second part

Comment: The variance is not defined if the mean is not finite. As pointed out above, if the second moment is finite then the mean is finite.

Comment: Thanks. My argument about L1 and L2 spaces are correct?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: You can still define it as $\inf_{a \in \Bbb R} \Bbb E[(X-a)^2]$, and in some books I've seen this done before proving that if said quantity is finite then the mean is finite (by Jensen) and that the infimum is achieved at $a = \mu$.

Comment: Yes, I think your argument is correct because probability spaces are finite measure spaces, $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

You just restated the problem. To prove it, use Cauchy Schwarz Inequality: $(E|X|)^2\leq EX^2$ for any r.v. $X$.Thus $E|X|\leq (EX^2)^{1/2}<\infty$ hence you have finite mean of $|X|$. Therefore, $EX^{+}<\infty, EX^{-}<\infty$ so $EX=EX^{+}-EX^{-}$is finite.

Comment: You proved that if $\operatorname{E[X^2]}$ is finite, then $\operatorname{E[X]}$ is finite too; but this is not what is asked here.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition), we know$\def\Var{{\textrm{Var}}\,}
\def\Cov{{\textrm{Cov}}\,}
\def\Corr{{\textrm{Corr}}\,}
\def\E{{\textrm{E}}\,}$ $\Var(X) = \E ( X - \E(X))^2$. Hence if variance is finite, $\E(X)$ has to be finite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2, how do we know that it can't be possible that $E[X^2]=E[X]^2=\infty$ but they are different infinites so somehow their difference is finite?