# Conceptual difference: infinite mean and non-existent mean

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, means

Let $X$ be a random variable with finite variance.
I know that this implies a finite mean.

Do I have to prove that or does it follow from the definition of the variance?

The variance is defined as
$V[X] =E[(X−E[X])^2]$

If the mean $E[X]$ would not exist, the variance would be undefined. Thus no finite variance without a defined mean.

If the mean $E[X]$ would be infinite, it could still be the case that $E[(X−E[X])^2]$ is finite, I would have to prove that it is not.

Mathematicians, how do you use "infinite" and "does not exist" interchangeably?

Note in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889384/does-finite-variance-imply-on-a-finite-mean) question, comments say "follows from the definition", while answer says "use Cauchy Schwarz", so I am not the only one who is confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Infinite mean and mean not existing are not one and the same. $X$ has mean $\infty$ if $EX^{+}=\infty$ and $EX^{-}<\infty$. Mean of $X$ dose not exist if $EX^{+}=\infty$ and $EX^{-}=\infty$ in which case you cannot assign any value, finite of infinite, to $EX$.

We can say the following: if $EX$ exists (finite or infinite) and $E(X-EX)^{2} <\infty$ then $EX$ is finite. [$E(X-EX)^{2} <\infty$ implies $X-EX$ is finite almost surely. Since $X$ has finite values this implies $EX$ is finite]. If $EX$ is not even defined we just cannot talk about variance of $X$.

Comment: What is $EX^+$? Could you answer "Do I have to prove that [finite variance implies finite mean] or does it follow from the definition of the variance?"

Comment: $X^{+}=\max \{X,0\}$.

Comment: thanks! But after your edit, I still don't know if  $E[(X−E[X])^2]<\infty \implies E[X]<\infty$ needs proof or not.

Comment: $E(X-EX)^{2} <\infty$ implies $X-EX$ is finite almost surely. Since $X$ has finite values this implies $EX$ is finite.